# Two-way ANOVA vs. simple differencing scheme

Tags: anova, frequentist

I am just learning about the ANOVA and have a question about an alternative approach that I thought was reasonable, but I am doubting now.

Suppose my data is in the form of a matrix $\mathbf{Y}$ of size $n \times p$, where the columns $\mathbf{y_i}$ correspond to $p$ different treatments and the rows to $n$ different blocking factors. Also, $n$ is large, say at least 600, and there are only around 5 or so treatments.

I am interested in what I believe are known as treatment contrasts, that is, I designate one of the $\mathbf{y_i}$ to be my control, say $\mathbf{y_1}$, and am interested in the means of treatment 2 minus treatment 1, treatment 3 minus treatment 1, and so on.

I'm still quite new to this but it seems that one way to do this would be a two-way ANOVA. However, I thought of a simple alternative approach and am trying to understand whether and if so, how, it is inferior to the ANOVA approach.

My thought was this: to compute e.g. the contrast between treatments 2 and 1, I first compute the vector of differences, $\pmb{\delta}_{21} = \mathbf{y_2} - \mathbf{y_1}$. Appealing to the central limit theorem, I then use the sample mean $\bar{Y}_{\delta_{21}}$ and sample variance $S_{\delta_{21}}^2$ to approximate the sampling distribution of the contrast as:

$$\theta_{21} \sim \mathcal{N}(\bar{Y}_{\delta_{21}}, \frac{S_{\delta_{21}}^2}{n})$$

I know that I should perhaps use a $t$ distribution here, but given the large sample size I think it's reasonable to just use a normal (that's not the main point here anyway).

I'd love to know if this is a reasonable way to go to calculate contrasts and if not, why not. What I like about it is that there seem to be fewer assumptions made than when using an ANOVA. But I'm also fairly new to all of this, so I want to know if there is something I'm missing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Calculating contrasts is common in the context of anova. Usually an F test is applied. One reason is that you can have multiple-degree-of-freedom contrasts, for example to compare treatments a, b, c, to d, e, f. There are also post-hoc tests to compare treatments pairwise. Given this, is there a reason you don't like these approaches, and are trying the develop something different?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Sal. I get your general point, which I understand to be "why reinvent the wheel". I'd like to understand though if there is anything wrong / clearly worse with the approach I describe. As for reasons why I might like this, it does seem to me that there are fewer assumptions here than in an ANOVA. For example, I am not sure my errors are normally distributed and have equal variance.